# The current URL didn't match any of these

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I found a Django project and failed to get it running in Docker container in the following way:

1. `git clone https://github.com/hotdogee/django-blast.git`
2. `$ cat requirements.txt` in this files the below dependencies had to be updated:

   - kombu==3.0.30
   - psycopg2==2.8.6

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /code/
```

For `docker-compose.yml` I use:

```
version: "3"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  dbi5k:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/dbi5k:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=django_i5k
      - POSTGRES_USER=django
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres


  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
```

I had to change:

```
$ vim i5k/settings_prod.py
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'postgres',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

and

```
$ vim i5k/settings.py
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'django_i5k',
        'USER': 'django',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'dbi5k',
        'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

Please below the logs

```
Attaching to djangoblast_dbik_1, djangoblast_db_1, djangoblast_web_1
dbik_1  | 
db_1    | 
dbik_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
dbik_1  | 
db_1    | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
db_1    | 
dbik_1  | 2021-05-19 10:45:54.221 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1    | 2021-05-19 10:45:55.264 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
db_1    | 2021-05-19 10:45:55.264 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
dbik_1  | 2021-05-19 10:45:54.221 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1    | 2021-05-19 10:45:55.264 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
dbik_1  | 2021-05-19 10:45:54.221 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
dbik_1  | 2021-05-19 10:45:54.226 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
dbik_1  | 2021-05-19 10:45:54.231 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-05-19 10:45:07 UTC
db_1    | 2021-05-19 10:45:55.271 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
dbik_1  | 2021-05-19 10:45:54.237 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1    | 2021-05-19 10:45:55.283 UTC [26] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2021-05-19 10:45:18 UTC
db_1    | 2021-05-19 10:45:55.292 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
web_1   | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py:29: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class social.apps.django_app.default.models.UserSocialAuth doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
web_1   |   class UserSocialAuth(models.Model, DjangoUserMixin):
web_1   | 
web_1   | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py:67: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class social.apps.django_app.default.models.Nonce doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
web_1   |   class Nonce(models.Model, DjangoNonceMixin):
web_1   | 
web_1   | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py:78: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class social.apps.django_app.default.models.Association doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
web_1   |   class Association(models.Model, DjangoAssociationMixin):
web_1   | 
web_1   | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py:91: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class social.apps.django_app.default.models.Code doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
web_1   |   class Code(models.Model, DjangoCodeMixin):
web_1   | 
web_1   | /code/suit/admin.py:5: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.contrib.contenttypes.generic is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Its contents have been moved to the fields, forms, and admin submodules of django.contrib.contenttypes.
web_1   |   from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
web_1   | 
web_1   | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py:29: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class social.apps.django_app.default.models.UserSocialAuth doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
web_1   |   class UserSocialAuth(models.Model, DjangoUserMixin):
web_1   | 
web_1   | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py:67: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class social.apps.django_app.default.models.Nonce doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
web_1   |   class Nonce(models.Model, DjangoNonceMixin):
web_1   | 
web_1   | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py:78: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class social.apps.django_app.default.models.Association doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
web_1   |   class Association(models.Model, DjangoAssociationMixin):
web_1   | 
web_1   | /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/social/apps/django_app/default/models.py:91: RemovedInDjango19Warning: Model class social.apps.django_app.default.models.Code doesn't declare an explicit app_label and either isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS or else was imported before its application was loaded. This will no longer be supported in Django 1.9.
web_1   |   class Code(models.Model, DjangoCodeMixin):
web_1   | 
web_1   | /code/suit/admin.py:5: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.contrib.contenttypes.generic is deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.9. Its contents have been moved to the fields, forms, and admin submodules of django.contrib.contenttypes.
web_1   |   from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
web_1   | 
web_1   | Performing system checks...
web_1   | 
web_1   | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1   | 
web_1   | You have unapplied migrations; your app may not work properly until they are applied.
web_1   | Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
web_1   | May 19, 2021 - 06:45:57
web_1   | Django version 1.8, using settings 'i5k.settings'
web_1   | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1   | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
web_1   | /code/rest_framework_swagger/urlparser.py:4: RemovedInDjango19Warning: django.utils.importlib will be removed in Django 1.9.
web_1   |   from django.utils.importlib import import_module
web_1   | 
web_1   | [19/May/2021 06:46:12]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 5610
web_1   | [19/May/2021 06:46:12]"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 5643
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

```
$ cat ./proxy/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from .views import proxy_view

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<url>.*)$', proxy_view, name='proxy_view'),
)
```

```
$ cat ./i5k/urls.py
from datetime import datetime
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from app.forms import BootstrapAuthenticationForm, BootStrapPasswordChangeForm, BootStrapPasswordResetForm, BootStrapSetPasswordForm

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
admin.autodiscover()
#admin.site.unregister(Site)

#from filebrowser.sites import site

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^home$', 'dashboard.views.dashboard', name='dashboard'),
    #url(r'^contact$', 'app.views.contact', name='contact'),
    url(r'^about', 'app.views.about', name='about'),
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include('filebrowser.urls')),
    # Uncomment the admin/doc line below to enable admin documentation:
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls'), name='doc'),
    url(r'^captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),
    url(r'^proxy/', include('proxy.urls', namespace='proxy')),
    url(r'^webapollo/', include('webapollo.urls', namespace='webapollo')),

    # user authentication
    url(r'^set_institution$', 'app.views.set_institution', name='set_institution'),
    url(r'^info_change$', 'app.views.info_change', name='info_change'),
    url(r'^register$', 'app.views.register', name='register'),
    url(r'^login/$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
        {
            'template_name': 'app/login.html',
            'authentication_form': BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title':'Log in',
                'year':datetime.now().year,
            },
        },
        name='login'),
    url(r'^logout$', 'app.views.logout_all', name='logout'),
    url(r'^password_reset$', 
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset',
        {
            'template_name': 'app/password_reset.html',
            'password_reset_form': BootStrapPasswordResetForm,
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Password reset',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            },
        },
        name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset_done$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_done',
        {
            'template_name': 'app/password_reset_done.html',
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Password reset sent',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            },
        },
        name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_confirm',
        {
            'template_name': 'app/password_reset_confirm.html',
            'set_password_form': BootStrapSetPasswordForm,
            'extra_context':
            {
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            },
        },
        name='password_reset_confirm'),
    url(r'^reset_complete$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset_complete',
        {
            'template_name': 'app/password_reset_complete.html',
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Password reset complete',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            },
        },
        name='password_reset_complete'),
    url(r'^password_change_done$',
        'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change_done',
        {
            'template_name': 'app/password_change_done.html',
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Password changed',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            },
        },
        name='password_change_done'),
    url(r'^password_change$',
        #'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',
        'app.views.password_change',
        {
            'template_name': 'app/password_change.html',
            'password_change_form': BootStrapPasswordChangeForm,
            'post_change_redirect': 'password_change_done',
            'extra_context':
            {
                'title': 'Change password',
                'year': datetime.now().year,
            },
        },
        name='password_change'),

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # BLAST
    url(r'^blast/', include('blast.urls', namespace='blast')),
    # BLAST
    url(r'^data/', include('data.urls', namespace='data')),
)
from django.conf import settings
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
        }),
        url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {
            'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT,
        }),
    )
```

```
$ cat ./rest_framework_swagger/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns
from django.conf.urls import url
from rest_framework_swagger.views import SwaggerResourcesView, SwaggerApiView, SwaggerUIView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', SwaggerUIView.as_view(), name="django.swagger.base.view"),
    url(r'^api-docs/$', SwaggerResourcesView.as_view(), name="django.swagger.resources.view"),
    url(r'^api-docs/(?P<path>.*)/?$', SwaggerApiView.as_view(), name='django.swagger.api.view'),
)
```

```
$ cat ./data/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from blast import views
from .api import FileViewSet, ItemViewSet, AccessionViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'file', FileViewSet)
router.register(r'item', ItemViewSet)
router.register(r'accession', AccessionViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls, namespace='api')),
    #url(r'^api/accessions/(?P<accession>.+)/$', AccessionDetail.as_view()),
    #url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    #url(r'^api-docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
)
```

```
# cat ./blast/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from blast import views
from .api import *
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter

router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'organism', OrganismViewSet)
router.register(r'seqtype', SequenceTypeViewSet)
router.register(r'blastdb', BlastDbViewSet)
router.register(r'seq', SequenceViewSet)
router.register(r'task', BlastQueryRecordViewSet)
router.register(r'user', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ex: /blast/
    url(r'^$', views.create, name='create'),
    #url(r'^iframe$', views.create, {'iframe': True}, name='iframe'),
    # ex: /blast/5/
    url(r'^(?P<task_id>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)$', views.retrieve, name='retrieve'),
    url(r'^(?P<task_id>[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/status$', views.status, name='status'),
    #url(r'^read_gff3/(?P<task_id>[0-9a-fA-F]*)/*(?P<dbname>[\w\-\|.]*)/*$', views.read_gff3, name='read_gff3'),
    url(r'^api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
    url(r'^api-docs/', include('rest_framework_swagger.urls')),
    url('^user-tasks/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)$', views.user_tasks),
```

```
$ cat ./webapollo/urls.py
from django.conf.urls import *
from . import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    #url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^panel$', views.panel, name='panel'),
    url(r'^admin/manage$', views.manage, name="manage"),
    url(r'^admin/bulk-remind$', views.bulk_remind, name="bulk-remind"),
    url(r'^admin/user/(?P<user_id>[0-9]+)$', views.user_permission, name="user_permission"),
    url(r'^admin/species/(?P<species_name>[a-z]{6})$', views.species_user, name="species_user"),
    url(r'^apply$', views.apply, name='apply'),
    url(r'^reject$', views.reject, name='reject'),
    url(r'^bulk-reject$', views.bulk_reject, name='bulk-reject'),
    url(r'^history$', views.history, name='history'),
    url(r'^approve$', views.approve, name='approve'),
    url(r'^bulk-approve$', views.bulk_approve, name='bulk-approve'),
    url(r'^remind$', views.remind, name='remind'),
    url(r'^adduser$', views.adduser, name='adduesr'),
    url(r'^remove$', views.remove, name='remove'),
    url(r'^eligible$', views.eligible, name='eligible'),
    url(r'^(?P<species_name>[a-z]{6})$', views.species, name="species"),
)
```

What did I miss?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you post url.py? Also you need to run `python manage.py migrate` for the first time

Comment: I've just added all `urls.py` into my question.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to docker-compose `command` so it will apply migrations whenever you start the container:

```
command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py makemigrations &&
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

Comment: I'd expect `makemigrations` to be run as part of the developer sequence.  `migrate` should happen in an `ENTRYPOINT` wrapper script, ending in `exec "$@"` to run the `CMD`; and then `CMD` should be the `runserver` line.  All of this should be part of the image and not overridden in the `docker-compose.yml` file.